# jqueryvalidation error appears in the textbox rather than label

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm having what seems to be a slightly bizarre problem (I think so anyway!!). I'm creating a small jquery mobile webapp and decided to use jqueryvalidation http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate my form data. It works BUT the error appears inside the textbox that should be filled rather than underneath it.

Does anyone have any suggestions? jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/chJ8B/3/

```
$().ready(function() {      
        // validate new customer form
        $("#newCustomer").validate({

            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element); // <- the default
        },

            rules: {
                surname: "required",
                phoneNumber: "required"


            },
            messages: {
                surname: "Please enter the surname/company name",
            }
    });
     });

<div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="surname">Company/Surname</label><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"  ></div>
<div class="ui-field-contain"><label for="forename">Forename</label><input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" value=""></div>
```

Comment: it is because of jQuery mobile styling.... try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Gsyrz/1/

Comment: Hi what did you change?

Comment: look at the `errorPlacement` - `insertAfter(element.parent())` - you may have to use some conditional statements to determine where to add the error element

Comment: Based on _element_ which receives the error, you need to place/reposition the error msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like because of jQuery mobile markup, try to insert the error element after the current element's parent

```
$("#newCustomer").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent()); // <- the default
    },
    rules: {
        surname: "required",
        phoneNumber: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        surname: "Please enter the surname/company name",
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Gsyrz/)

---

You may have to add some conditional placements based on the type of markup you are dealing with in certain situations

Answer (score 0):

Update the error placement with this:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
  error.insertAfter(element.parent()); // <- the default
}
```